# Run excel function over multiple rows and columns and get AGGREGATE without the need for additional columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have this data set, for example:

[image: Example data set]

Based on a comment, here's that same example data in CSV format that should properly import into Excel:

```
Compute (),Serverless (),Compute Containers (),Databases (),Total ()
EC2 --- 9,Lambda --- 1,"App Mesh --- 0
ECS --- 3
EKS --- 2","DocumentDB --- 0
DynamoDB --- 5
ElastiCache --- 0
RDS --- 2
Redshift --- 3",Total --- 
EC2 --- 7,Lambda --- 2,"App Mesh --- 0
ECS --- 0
EKS --- 1","DocumentDB --- 0
DynamoDB --- 5
ElastiCache --- 0
RDS --- 13
Redshift --- 1",Total ---
```

I'd like to be able to do two things:

1. I'd like to be able to sum all numbers contained within cells across a range of columns (A through D) and output that total on column E.
2. I'm also looking to then use that same *sum all numbers contained within cells* but across the rows of each column, rather than the column, and supply a total count for all rows within that column in the header of the column.

I've been able to do #2 with some success, but it requires writing additional columns for each source column in order to do the magic to first get the combined total for cell for each row...store it in that new column...then in the header I simply sum the range of that new column.

For examples, summing up column A, I can use/create column F for storing that total:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("---",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))+3,99),0))
```

And then A1 becomes `="Compute (" & SUBTOTAL(109,F2:F3) & ")"` which is nice because it does work dynamically for both removing/hiding rows with filters and when hidden.

That monster allows me to nicely sum the total of all numbers that appear no matter line breaks or empty...but I'd very much prefer to skip the need for that additional column but have not found a way to make this into something that works that way.

Desired result would be:

[image: Desired result]

[EDIT: I wasn't clear that "sum" is not exactly what's needed as it needs to also change when content is hidden/filtered]
...and dynamically change for hidden/filtered content (ie: `SUBTOTAL` or, ideally, `AGGREGATE`).

Comment: Any chance to put your sample data into a markdown table? Try here: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: @TerryW you know I tried for hours and nothing worked well because of the line breaks, even when saying line breaks should work and persist, even though it displays fine in the source CSV in excel and after being converted with pandas to xlsx. I've added CSV version which should help import/copy the example. Thanks

Comment: Hi @TerryW ... the numbers can be much larger than 10, yes, they may even reach 10000+. The text strings are the same, only the numbers change for each cell, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note, my solution only works if the number at the end of each text string is a **positive number
> between `0` and `9999999999` (10 digits) inclusive**. Some rework is required if you require a solution that works for
> negative values and/or more than 10 digits.

My solution also requires the use of a supporting row to store the desired column headers. Suppose this is in range `A1:E1` as shown below:

[image: Headers]

Suppose the sample data is in the range `A3:E5` (I added one row for testing purpose). You want to return the sum of rows in range `A2:E2` and return the sum of columns in range `E3:E5`.

In Cell `E3`, please enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
="Total --- "&LET(x,SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A3:D3,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",10))),",",REPT(" ",10)),SUM(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(MID(x,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FIND("---",x,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(x),1,1))))+4,10),",",""),0)))
```

In Cell `A2`, please enter the following formula and drag it to the right:

```
=A1&TEXT(LET(x,SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A5,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",10))),",",REPT(" ",10)),SUM(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(MID(x,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FIND("---",x,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(x),1,1))))+4,10),",",""),0)))," (#)")
```

[image: Solution]

Some explanations, I first used the **ARRAYTOTEXT+SUBSTITUTE** function to convert the target range into a text string and replace all line breaks and comma signs with a 10-character length of blanks, then you should have something like below:

`EC2 --- 9           Lambda --- 1           App Mesh --- 0                    ECS --- 3                    EKS --- 2           DocumentDB --- 0          DynamoDB --- 5          ElastiCache --- 0          RDS --- 2          Reshift --- 3`

Then I used a combination of **SUBSTITUTE+MID+UNIQUE+TRANSPOSE+SEQUENCE** to find the location of each number based on the position of `---` in the text string, return the numbers into a vertical array, and lastly use the **IFERROR+SUM** function to add up the numbers.

The **LET** function allows me to store the **ARRAYTOTEXT+SUBSTITUTE** function into a name called `x`, which can be easily referred to in the subsequent calculations. Without using **LET**, the formula will be extremely long and hard to read.

I would say **FILTERXML** is a better function to use in this case as it is not limited to the number of digits of each number in the text string, while mine can only work for up to ten digits.

Comment: That's helpful. Any chance you'd know how to make it work with SUBTOTAL rather than SUM? I've updated the question as one of the requirements is that it dynamically changes for hidden/filtered content.

Comment: This is the best, most reliable answer that worked with my special requirements so I've accepted it. Thanks for your help...really good stuff, learned a lot. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure how to fashion AGGREGATE to work with this because that's ultimately what I need. If I can't figure it out, I may open a new question and ping the link here ;))

Comment: @TryTryAgain with the help of a support column F using this formula in cell F3 `=SUBTOTAL(103,A3)=1` and drag it down to F5, and change the formula for `x` to `SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(IF($F3:$F5,A3:A5),CHAR(10),REPT(" ",10))),",",REPT(" ",10))` in the **LET** function, the summed result will exclude the hidden column, but so far I can only make it work for summing the rows in the column header, but unable to work out how to do it for summing columns at the end of each row.

Answer (score 1):

1] In `E2`, formula copied down :

```
="TOTAL --- "&SUMPRODUCT(--TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A2:D2&" "),CHAR(10)," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$50)*99-98,99),"0;;0;\0"))
```

2] In `A1`, formula copied across right :

```
="Compute ("&SUMPRODUCT(--TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A2:A3&" "),CHAR(10)," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$50)*99-98,99),"0;;0;\0"))&")"
```

Then ,

In B1:E1, change the header name inside the formula  into "Serverless", "Compute Containers", "Databases" and "TOTAL" in accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, @bosco_yip thanks. Sorry to be a stickler, any way you can work in a subtotal with this instead of sumproduct so that hidden/filtered out items don't add to the count?

Comment: Try [E2], =SUMPRODUCT(--TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(CELL("width",A1)>0,A1,""),IF(CELL("width",B1)>0,B1,""),IF(CELL("width",C1)>0,C1,""),IF(CELL("width",D1)>0,D1,"")),CHAR(10)," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$50)*99-98,99),"0;;0;\0"))

Comment: Thanks, I had to `/2` divide the results by two to get proper results...but it didn't help for hidden. The result stayed the same :/

Answer (score 0):

`FILTERXML()` with `TEXTJOIN()` may give you desired result.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:D2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")," --- ", "</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"))
```

[image]

> Edit:

If you don't have `TEXTJOIN()` then can try below formula. `FILTERXML()` is available on `Excel2013` and later. In this case formula will longer as many column you have in every row.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10)," --- ")," --- ","</s><s>")&"</s><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10)," --- ")," --- ","</s><s>")&"</s><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(10)," --- ")," --- ","</s><s>")&"</s><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,CHAR(10)," --- ")," --- ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"))
```

Comment: I get an invalid name error, looks like I don't have `FILTERXML`. Is this cross compatible?

Comment: What is your excel version? I think you do not have `TEXTJOIN()` as it available in `Excel2019` and `Excel365`.

Comment: MacOS (via O365 subscription): version 16.47.21032301 ... Strange, googling says both "What's new in Excel 2019 for Mac [...] TEXTJOIN" and also "TEXTJOIN is a new function, available in Office 365 and Excel 2019." And I just did a simple test `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,G1:H1)` and it worked... Not sure why it's not working with your solution. ... what I don't have is FILTERXML .. it doesn't show up when I start typing it like all other built in functions do...including TEXTJOIN :(

Comment: Oh! MAC excel and Excel web edition do not have `FILTERXML()` formula.

Comment: Here is documentation. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve without `FILTERXML`? I'm able to achieve within one cell as described in my question, not able to create the "every row" formula you did for when `TEXTJOIN` is unavailable but for when `FILTERXML` is unavailable though.